# Fantasy kids' game for Nintendo DS in which the occupants of a duck or chicken town are sucked into a book and you have to play minigames to save them

Tags: story-identification, magic, video-games

This game was out on Nintendo DS; I played it like seven years ago.

You live in a duck (or chicken?) town and this magician guy brings a book out to read a story to you and your friends, but the book is cursed and sucks almost everyone inside. Now, you have to go into different storybooks (including versions of "Jack and the Beanstalk" and "The Ugly Duckling") and play little minigames to save them and progress.

Meanwhile, evil ducks -- I think coloured black -- have invaded the town and compete against you in the minigames. You go to the different places in town symbolising the four elements: volcano (fire), sea (water), forest (Earth or plant or something) and a lighthouse, I think, as electricity, finally defeating the evil book -- which has, like, turned into a book dragon -- and bringing peace back.

Please, does anyone know the name? "The Ugly Duckling" story was also especially significant because the character in the story, the ugly duckling, turned out to be a phoenix and appears once you progress in the volcano area and helps you out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is ***[Final Fantasy Fables: Chocobo Tales](https://finalfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Final_Fantasy_Fables:_Chocobo_Tales)*** (2006).

> *Final Fantasy Fables: Chocobo Tales* (チョコボと魔法の絵本, *Chocobo to Mahō no Ehon*, lit. Chocobo and the Magical Picture Book) is an adventure game by Square Enix for the Nintendo DS.

The [protagonist](https://finalfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Chocobo_(Chocobo_series)) of the game is a young [chocobo](https://finalfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Chocobo), a breed of flightless bird that exists within the *Final Fantasy* universe.

> Chocobo, also called Poulet (プーレ, Pūre?), is the main protagonist in the *Chocobo* series. A young chocobo, he is the only chocobo who doesn't speak the language of the humans, but he is certainly the bravest.

According to the wiki site for the game, the [plot](https://finalfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Chocobo_(Chocobo_series)#Final_Fantasy_Fables:_Chocobo_Tales) involves a magician called [Croma](https://finalfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Croma) bringing a strange book to Chocobo Farm, where the protagonist lives. When the book is opened, a demon called [Bebuzzu](https://finalfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Bebuzzu) is released and he sucks all the chocobos into cards.

> Chocobo was discovered by Shirma while still young. He was one of the many casualties of the great war, but Shirma took him to Chocobo Farm on a far away island. There he lived happily with the other Chocobos.
>
> One day, Croma brought a strange tome to the farm. Unable to open it, Chocobo had a look at it and managed to unlock it. Upon doing so, he released the evil demon Bebuzzu, who then sucked up all the Chocobos into cards.

The opening cut-scene shows the book coming to life after a minigame is completed to open it, and sucking all the nearby chocobos, except for the protagonist, inside. The book is opened at around the 3:30 mark in the video clip below. It starts sucking the chocobos inside at around the 5:00 mark.

According to the wiki site, the [gameplay](https://finalfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Final_Fantasy_Fables:_Chocobo_Tales#Gameplay) involves the player finding and being transported into picture books in order to complete minigames based on adaptations of classic fairy tales.

> Gameplay consists of exploring the environment to find picture books. The player is transported into the pop-up worlds of the book must complete different mini-games to unlock the next part of the story, new cards, chocobos, and books.
>
> The stories in the books are mostly based on classical fairy tales, but are adapted to suit the *Final Fantasy* universe. The stories' protagonists are chocobos and other *Final Fantasy* creatures.

One of the stories is called "[Titan and the Beanstalk](https://finalfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Titan_and_the_Beanstalk)" and is based on "Jack and the Beanstalk."

> Titan and the Beanstalk is a story from *Final Fantasy Fables: Chocobo Tales*. The story is about a young boy who is robbed while having to run an errand for his mother. He then finds a magical bean, which he throws out through his window. Overnight, the bean grows into a giant stalk which he climbs all the way to the top, where he finds the home of a giant.
>
> The story is based on *Jack and the Beanstalk*.

Another is called "[The Ugly Chocoling](https://finalfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/The_Ugly_Chocoling)" and is based on "The Ugly Duckling." The wiki description notes that the titular character of this story is revealed to be a young phoenix.

> The Ugly Chocoling is a story from *Final Fantasy Fables: Chocobo Tales*. The story is about a young chocobo who seems to be cursed with fiery feathers on top of looking rather awkward in comparison to the rest of his peers. In two of the epilogues, it is revealed that he is in fact a young Phoenix and not a chocobo.
>
> The story is based on *The Ugly Duckling*, a fairy tale written by Hans Christian Andersen, along with some references to the Parable of the Prodigal Son.

Comment: Yes thank you so much!! all I could remember was Choko Boco but nothing came up LOL now I see I was so close yet so far... THANKS again!!!! Also esp thanks for so much detail in your answer. Reading all that again makes me so nostalgic TuT